# Why is [1,[2,3]] != [1,[2,3]]

Tags: javascript, logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Why does `[1,[2,3]] == [1,[2,3]]` evaluate to false?

Also, why does this happen:

```
var g = { a:1, b:2, c:3 };
g == { a:1, b:2, c:3 }; // false!!
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey why? `[1,[2,3]] === [1,[2,3]]` is also `false`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It's still false

Comment: @kojiro thats because they are not the same object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'd say that's _even more false_ if there is such a thing. :)

Comment: The algorithm for the equals operator is defined in [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), Section 11.9.3. It all boils down to rule 1. f.:

"1. If Type(*x*) is the same as Type(*y*), then […] f. Return **true** if *x* and *y* refer to the same object. Otherwise, return **false**."

You are comparing two objects, which might have the same content - yet are not referring to the same object.

Comment: As Zack mentions below in one of the answer's comments, you can use the JSON.stringify method to compare two object's values. This however is only backwards compatible so far unless you add the standard JSON javascript library to your project. `JSON.stringify({a:1}) == JSON.stringify({a:1})`

Comment: It's like in Java and probably other OO languages: Comparing two objects using the equals operator only results in true if both reference the same object. Why does this confuse people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is a shortcut to make an array literal instead of calling `new Array()` and then populating it.  It's a similar story for `{}`.  In your example, you are actually comparing by reference instead of by value.  Two objects constructed with the `new` operator point to different locations in memory, and when you use the `==` operator you are actually saying "do these objects point to the same location in memory?".  To do a by-value comparison like you're expecting, you would need to iterate through the members of each array/object you're comparing and compare each value one-by-one.

Comment: Is there a way to get them to be equal?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, convert your object to a json and compare. http://jsfiddle.net/VzA55/

Comment: @PitaJ They would have to be *the same object* to be truly equal.  Meaning they were constructed by the same call.  Now, if you want to test for value equality you *can* do that.  One easy (not the most performant) way is to convert them both to Strings. `JSON.stringify(g) === JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2, c:3})` is `true` and is in-line with your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

Because [] and {} creates new instances of objects and they are not equal.